# Creating child entries in QGIS form with Spatialite many-to-many relationship

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, spatialite, many-to-many

I am trying to reproduce the example from [Introducing many-to-many (N-M) relations](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#introducing-many-to-many-n-m-relations) using Spatialite. Creating the tables and the relations works fine, but when I try to create a child element in a form in QGIS, the junction table cannot be saved because of a failed foreign key constraint. What am I doing wrong?

This is what I did:

1. Create a new Spatialite database using `spatialite_gui` (SQLite version 3.22.0, SpatiaLite version 4.3.0a)
2. Create three tables, `airports`, `airlines`, and a junction table `airports_airlines` using the following SQL statements:

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE airports (
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,   
       airport_name text NOT NULL
   );

   CREATE TABLE airlines (
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
       airline_name
       text NOT NULL
   );

   CREATE TABLE airports_airlines (
       id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,   
       airport_fk INTEGER
           REFERENCES airports (id)
           ON DELETE CASCADE
           ON UPDATE CASCADE
           DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
       airline_fk INTEGER
           REFERENCES airlines (id)
           ON DELETE CASCADE
           ON UPDATE CASCADE
           DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
   );
   ```
3. Load the three tables in QGIS (version 3.12.0).
4. In Project Properties | Data Sources activate the option "Automatically create transaction groups where possible"
5. In Project Properties | Relations, set the relations with the junction table as shown below:
   [image]
6. In the layer properties, set the cardinality of the relation to `airports (id)` and `airlines (id)`, respectively, add the relations widget to the drag-and-drop form and remove the `id` text widget, as shown below:
   [image]
7. Try to create a new airline and an associated airport at the same time. This seems to work fine at first, but trying to save the layers fails with the following error messages

   ```
   CRITICAL    Layer airports_airlines : SQLite error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
             SQL: INSERT INTO "airports_airlines"( "airport_fk","airline_fk") VALUES ( ?,?)
   CRITICAL    Layer airports_airlines : SQLite error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
             SQL: INSERT INTO "airports_airlines"( "airport_fk","airline_fk") VALUES ( ?,?)
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Do you have relation errors in the logs panel?

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca: Oh, yes, there are the following warnings: "WARNING    Layer airports_airlines, field airport_fk: Missing Relation in configuration" and "WARNING    Layer airports_airlines, field airline_fk: Missing Relation in configuration". Not sure how to interpret that, though, because the required relations are set up.

Comment: You need to use autoincrement for the id as at the moment, when you create any element, it does not have one set in the database. I thing that's why it can't work. Replace id `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,` with `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,`. In the original post/tutorial, they use a type called `serial` present in PostgreSQL and not equivalent in SQLite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726028/sqlite3-serial-type-wasnt-incremented/19726143

Comment: @ThomasG77: Ah yes, thanks, that gets me a little bit further! However, saving the junction table now fails with a `foreign key error` (see my edited post). Could this be related to the fact that QGIS uses a transaction group for PostgreSQL and Geopackage layers, but apparently not for Spatialite layers?

Comment: See https://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/3.14/#spatialite-provider-transactions as it may change the behaviour in QGIS 3.14 and maybe solve the problem?!

Comment: @ThomasG77: Thanks for following up! Yes, it's almost fixed in 3.14 - the foreign key constraint is now evaluated for both the new feature and the new child feature at the same time in a transaction group, which avoids the `foreign key error`. It turned out that getting the example from my question to work completely also requires evaluating the `id` field on the server side, and that change was [not included in 3.14.0](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/37249#issuecomment-645660890) to allow for more thorough testing. In the current development version this works already.